# Prevent mapstruct from using the single object mapping function in list of object mapping function

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, mapstruct

I have 2 micro-services: let's call them A and B.

The entities handled by B in which there is a reference to an entity of A are implemented as a simple Long id (eg. the groupId)

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "WorkShifts")
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class WorkShiftEntity extends BaseEntitySerial {
    @Column(name = "group_id")
    private Long groupId;
    private String description;
    @Column(name = "start_time")
    private Time startTime;
    @Column(name = "end_time")
    private Time endTime;
    @Column(name = "work_shift")
    private Integer workShift;
}
```

What I want to achieve is to populate the missing group data of B (held by A) using mapstruct.
So far I tryed to use an @AfterMapping function to request the missing data from A. My mapper is:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = LocalTimeMapper.class, builder = @Builder(disableBuilder = true), config = CommonMapperConfig.class)
public abstract class WorkShiftMapper extends BaseMapper implements IBaseMapper<WorkShiftEntity, WorkShiftDTO, Long>, LogSupport {
    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Mapping(target = "groupId", source = "group.id")
    public abstract WorkShiftEntity dtoToEntity(WorkShiftDTO workShiftDTO);

    @AfterMapping
    public void afterEntityToDto(final WorkShiftEntity workShiftEntity, @MappingTarget final WorkShiftDTO workShiftDTO) {
        if (workShiftEntity == null) {
            return;
        }
        GroupDTO groupDTO = EcofinderUtils.getGroupDTO(restTemplate, workShiftEntity.getGroupId());

        try {
            GenericUtils.enhanceDTOForAttributeWithDTO(workShiftDTO, groupDTO, "group");
        } catch (InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            getLogger().error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @AfterMapping
    public void afterEntityToDtoList(final List<WorkShiftEntity> workShiftEntity, @MappingTarget final List<WorkShiftDTO> workShiftDTO) {
        if (workShiftEntity == null || workShiftEntity.size() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        List<GroupDTO> groups = EcofinderUtils.getAllGroupDTOById(restTemplate, workShiftEntity.stream().map(WorkShiftEntity::getGroupId).distinct().toList());

        try {
            //Compile the resulting DTOs with the data got from the registry
            //Group
            GenericUtils.enhanceDTOListWithDataFromDTOJoiningEntities(workShiftDTO, groups, workShiftEntity, "group", "groupId");
        } catch (AppException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            getLogger().error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The implemented interface which gives me the mapping functions is:

```
public interface IBaseMapper<T extends BaseEntity<K>, D extends IBaseDTO<K>, K extends Serializable> {
    D entityToDto(T entity);

    List<D> entityToDtoList(List<T> entity);

    T dtoToEntity(D dto);
}
```

The problem with the generated code is that the function that maps a list of entities to a list of DTOs uses the entityToDto for every entity, resulting in n requests to A. After that , the other @AfterMapping function is called (the one that collects all the ids and pulls all the data in only one request, which is the ONLY one that should be used while mapping a list).

```
    //GENERATED CODE BY MAPSTRUCT
    @Override
    public WorkShiftDTO entityToDto(WorkShiftEntity workShiftEntity) {
        if ( workShiftEntity == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        WorkShiftDTO workShiftDTO = new WorkShiftDTO();

        workShiftDTO.setId( workShiftEntity.getId() );
        workShiftDTO.setDescription( workShiftEntity.getDescription() );
        workShiftDTO.setStartTime( localTimeMapper.map( workShiftEntity.getStartTime() ) );
        workShiftDTO.setEndTime( localTimeMapper.map( workShiftEntity.getEndTime() ) );
        workShiftDTO.setWorkShift( workShiftEntity.getWorkShift() );

        afterEntityToDto( workShiftEntity, workShiftDTO );

        return workShiftDTO;
    }
    @Override
    public List<WorkShiftDTO> entityToDtoList(List<WorkShiftEntity> entity) {
        //more code...
        List<WorkShiftDTO> list = new ArrayList<WorkShiftDTO>( entity.size() );
        for ( WorkShiftEntity workShiftEntity : entity ) {
            list.add( entityToDto( workShiftEntity ) );
        }

        afterEntityToDtoList( entity, list );

        return list;
    }
```

Is there a way to make mapstruct implement the entityToDto function twice where one version uses the @AfterMapping function and the other doesn't in order to make the entityToDtoList function use the version without the @AfterMapping call?

Something like:

```
    @Override
    public WorkShiftDTO entityToDto(WorkShiftEntity workShiftEntity) {
        if ( workShiftEntity == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        WorkShiftDTO workShiftDTO = new WorkShiftDTO();

        workShiftDTO.setId( workShiftEntity.getId() );
        workShiftDTO.setDescription( workShiftEntity.getDescription() );
        workShiftDTO.setStartTime( localTimeMapper.map( workShiftEntity.getStartTime() ) );
        workShiftDTO.setEndTime( localTimeMapper.map( workShiftEntity.getEndTime() ) );
        workShiftDTO.setWorkShift( workShiftEntity.getWorkShift() );

        afterEntityToDto( workShiftEntity, workShiftDTO );

        return workShiftDTO;
    }
    public WorkShiftDTO entityToDtoNoAfter(WorkShiftEntity workShiftEntity) {
        if ( workShiftEntity == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        WorkShiftDTO workShiftDTO = new WorkShiftDTO();

        workShiftDTO.setId( workShiftEntity.getId() );
        workShiftDTO.setDescription( workShiftEntity.getDescription() );
        workShiftDTO.setStartTime( localTimeMapper.map( workShiftEntity.getStartTime() ) );
        workShiftDTO.setEndTime( localTimeMapper.map( workShiftEntity.getEndTime() ) );
        workShiftDTO.setWorkShift( workShiftEntity.getWorkShift() );

        return workShiftDTO;
    }
    @Override
    public List<WorkShiftDTO> entityToDtoList(List<WorkShiftEntity> entity) {
        //more code...
        List<WorkShiftDTO> list = new ArrayList<WorkShiftDTO>( entity.size() );
        for ( WorkShiftEntity workShiftEntity : entity ) {
            list.add( entityToDtoNoAfter( workShiftEntity ) );
        }

        afterEntityToDtoList( entity, list );

        return list;
    }
```

Other approaches are welcome, this one only feels the more natural to me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After around two days of intensive research and many attempts I think I have found a decent solution.

I can give the functions a name and by doing so they sort of work like they have a specific scope.
The mapper interface becomes:

```
public interface IBaseMapper<T extends BaseEntity<K>, D extends IBaseDTO<K>, K extends Serializable> {
    @BeanMapping(qualifiedByName = "EntityToDTO")
    D entityToDto(T entity);

    @Named("EntityToDTOList")
    public abstract D entityToDTOListEntity(T entity);

    @IterableMapping(qualifiedByName = "EntityToDTOList")
    List<D> entityToDtoList(List<T> entity);

    T dtoToEntity(D dto);
}
```

So that I can group toghether all the functions I need.

The mapper abstract class:

```
    @Mapping(target = "groupId", source = "group.id")
    public abstract WorkShiftEntity dtoToEntity(WorkShiftDTO workShiftDTO);

    @AfterMapping
    @Named("EntityToDTO")
    public void afterEntityToDto(final WorkShiftEntity workShiftEntity, @MappingTarget final WorkShiftDTO workShiftDTO) {
        if (workShiftEntity == null) {
            return;
        }
        GroupDTO groupDTO = EcofinderUtils.getGroupDTO(restTemplate, workShiftEntity.getGroupId());

        try {
            GenericUtils.enhanceDTOForAttributeWithDTO(workShiftDTO, groupDTO, "group");
        } catch (InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            getLogger().error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @AfterMapping
    @Named("EntityToDTOList")
    public void afterEntityToDtoList(final List<WorkShiftEntity> workShiftEntity, @MappingTarget final List<WorkShiftDTO> workShiftDTO) {
        if (workShiftEntity == null || workShiftEntity.size() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        List<GroupDTO> groups = EcofinderUtils.getAllGroupDTOById(restTemplate, workShiftEntity.stream().map(WorkShiftEntity::getGroupId).distinct().toList());

        try {
            //Compile the resulting DTOs with the data got from the registry
            //Group
            GenericUtils.enhanceDTOListWithDataFromDTOJoiningEntities(workShiftDTO, groups, workShiftEntity, "group", "groupId");
        } catch (AppException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            getLogger().error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

By doing so, the generated Impl class is:

```
@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2022-05-20T15:08:38+0200",
    comments = "version: 1.4.2.Final, compiler: javac, environment: Java 17.0.1 (Oracle Corporation)"
)
@Component
public class WorkShiftMapperImpl extends WorkShiftMapper {

    @Autowired
    private LocalTimeMapper localTimeMapper;

    @Override
    public WorkShiftDTO entityToDto(WorkShiftEntity entity) {
        if ( entity == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        WorkShiftDTO workShiftDTO = new WorkShiftDTO();

        workShiftDTO.setId( entity.getId() );
        workShiftDTO.setDescription( entity.getDescription() );
        workShiftDTO.setStartTime( localTimeMapper.map( entity.getStartTime() ) );
        workShiftDTO.setEndTime( localTimeMapper.map( entity.getEndTime() ) );
        workShiftDTO.setWorkShift( entity.getWorkShift() );

        afterEntityToDto( entity, workShiftDTO );

        return workShiftDTO;
    }

    @Override
    public WorkShiftDTO entityToDTOListEntity(WorkShiftEntity entity) {
        if ( entity == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        WorkShiftDTO workShiftDTO = new WorkShiftDTO();

        workShiftDTO.setId( entity.getId() );
        workShiftDTO.setDescription( entity.getDescription() );
        workShiftDTO.setStartTime( localTimeMapper.map( entity.getStartTime() ) );
        workShiftDTO.setEndTime( localTimeMapper.map( entity.getEndTime() ) );
        workShiftDTO.setWorkShift( entity.getWorkShift() );

        return workShiftDTO;
    }

    @Override
    public List<WorkShiftDTO> entityToDtoList(List<WorkShiftEntity> entity) {
        if ( entity == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        List<WorkShiftDTO> list = new ArrayList<WorkShiftDTO>( entity.size() );
        for ( WorkShiftEntity workShiftEntity : entity ) {
            list.add( entityToDTOListEntity( workShiftEntity ) );
        }

        afterEntityToDtoList( entity, list );

        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public WorkShiftEntity dtoToEntity(WorkShiftDTO workShiftDTO) {
        if ( workShiftDTO == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        WorkShiftEntity workShiftEntity = new WorkShiftEntity();

        workShiftEntity.setGroupId( workShiftDTOGroupId( workShiftDTO ) );
        workShiftEntity.setId( workShiftDTO.getId() );
        workShiftEntity.setDescription( workShiftDTO.getDescription() );
        workShiftEntity.setStartTime( localTimeMapper.map( workShiftDTO.getStartTime() ) );
        workShiftEntity.setEndTime( localTimeMapper.map( workShiftDTO.getEndTime() ) );
        workShiftEntity.setWorkShift( workShiftDTO.getWorkShift() );

        return workShiftEntity;
    }

    private Long workShiftDTOGroupId(WorkShiftDTO workShiftDTO) {
        if ( workShiftDTO == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        GroupDTO group = workShiftDTO.getGroup();
        if ( group == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        Long id = group.getId();
        if ( id == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        return id;
    }
}
```

Which is exaclty what I was looking for.